# Unable to add an app to Samsung Smart Tv Emulator

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I'd be very grateful if someone could offer me advice getting on getting the Samsung TV emulator to work as I need to test a web app and I have spent more than a day trying different things without success.

I'm using Windows 10. Tizen Studio 3.0, Tv Emulator 4

When I look in the apps section I only see the internet option. When I attempt to drag a sample app into the emulator I see a not permitted icon.

I attempted to access the app via inbuilt browser, either via localhost or a remote address, it fails because it doesn't have network access. It is in Nat mode, in the default configuration. I don't know which ports to use for port forwarding and I followed the bridged network instructions but that doesn't work either. 
I tried adding a shared folder called Apps and adding a sample app to that but nothing appeared there either.

I have created a test certificate, I'm not sure how to apply it or if it is automatically applied.
Any advice would be very welcome because I've run out of ideas.

Comment: After following the steps in the answer below, I encountered a problem saying Closed Closed after attempting to run as.   https://developer.tizen.org/forums/general-support/serious-bugs-developing-tizen-tv   a solution in the above forum help me to install a sample app. you need to use the command line "tizen install -t [model] -n [widget name].wgt  -- [folder]"

Comment: What is "folder" and "model" ? (for example: UE60KU6072 - is this model or not? )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to install the application you must upload your certificate to the emulator (or TV), please find the instructions under [creating certificates for Samsung TV devs](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/getting-started/setting-up-sdk/creating-certificates)

The best way to get your certificate working is to create it after boot the emulator, doing this, the certificate manager will get the emulator DUID automatically

Drag and drop operations are not supported by the tv emulator, so you must use 'Run as...' option (right click on the project name) and select 'Tizen web application'

**UPDATE**:
In order save your time, is better to downgrade to Tizen Studio 1.3 and TV Extensions 3, most of problems will disappear and you will be able to develop the same apps (incluiding 2015 & 2016 models)

Please follow this guide [HOW TO GET BACK TIZEN STUDIO 1.3 AND TV EXTENSIONS 3.0](http://blog.infernored.com/how-to-get-back-tizen-studio-1.3-and-tv-extensions-3.0)

So after get back your old 1.3 IDE (using a new workspace)

- create and boot your TV Emulator (tv-extensions 3)
- create your certificates (remember to Sign in with your Samsung Developer account) linking them to the DUID
- Open the 'Connection Explorer' view, right click the emulator and select 'Permit to install applications'
- Right click the project name and select 'Run As... Tizen Web Application'
- Cross your fingers

Comment: Many thanks, I went to reply here but my comment was too long so I've posted below. Thanks again.

Comment: If someone is reading this experiencing the same problem as I was then I recommend the following: Don't install 1.3. It wouldn't install for me. I said that the relevant JDK was missing. it wasn't . I also tried with 2.5 but it wouldn't connect to my network, so I couldn't download any of the necessary tools. So I had to try again with v3. I followed the first part of this answer, relating the Samsung certificate. Then  I didn't use the tv sample app I used sample > extended custom > tv samsung v4.0. and I didn't receive the closed closed error.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, I really appreciate it! I followed the steps and it got me much closer than I've been before but it still won't load the app. It appears in device manager and I was able to add the certificate there. However, it doesn't appear as in the Samsung screenshots. I can't see the directory structure to the right hand side and the connection button is in light blue, as if it isn't an option.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZukb.jpg)

When I try to add the app via the device manager it says sdbCommandRejectedException:closed
when I try via Run As the problem appears as Closed, closed.
I have tried numerous version 4 and 5 sample apps. And I tried with a blank sample app and they all have the closed closed error.

I searched and found this forum entry relating to the closed closed error.  https://developer.tizen.org/forums/sdk-ide/tizen-studio-cannot-run-application-on-smart-tv

It maybe to do with the version of the tv emulator and or the sdk? Someone was able to run a sample app using a tizen.bat
but I couldn't find that bat. I'm using sdk 3.0 and he was running an earlier version. 
What a time drain this tizen emulator is. If you do have any suggestions I'd be very grateful to hear them. Thanks.

Comment: Updated answer :)

Comment: PS: Please note, from the IDE, the only way to install the app is using the 'Run as... Tizen web Application' option.

There are some CLI commands, but most of 2.X Tizen versions have problems with the CLI tools for TV developments, so is better to use the IDE run as option

Comment: Thanks for your help again. I did try using the 'Run as... Tizen web Application' and the Debug as.... Tizen web Application but I receive the Closed Closed. error.

Comment: But I'll try with your updated answer if the command line option stops working. Thanks

Comment: I always have 'Closed' error using 2.X tizen studio version. Most of functionality don't work under these versions, it seems most of them only works with gear or tizen mobiles.