# Can't install app on TV with Tizen studio 3.2 and MacOS

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app

I have previous experience with TV app development but I used 2.4 T.studio and Windows. After a while when I started creating another app on MacOS on latest Tizen studio I always get an error when app is installing on TV. Error looks like this "org.tizen.sdblib.exception.sdbCommandRejectedException"

- I've tried to change JDK from 11 to 10 but result is the same.
- I tried both certificates Tizen and Samsung but result is the same on emulator and TV.
- I have JDK 10
- Device year is 2018
- Tizen studio 3.2
- TV SDK 5.0/4.0

Is there a way to fix this? 
Is Windows users has the same problem?

Comment: When you deploy an app to the display there is a log of the progress. What does the log say?

Answer (score 3):

Tizen studio has lot of issues depending the TV model and SDK tools. Due you cannot develop TV apps for old model groups using latest SDK (for example you cannot use Tizen Studio 3.X to develop apps for Tizen 2.4, that is 2016 and previous) I recommend use Tizen Studio 1.3, due you will be able to develop apps from 2015 until today SDK.

Please check [Unable to add an app to Samsung Smart Tv Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53370013/unable-to-add-an-app-to-samsung-smart-tv-emulator/53422225#53422225)

Comment: could you please share TV extension 3.0, because link in article doesn't work for me?

Comment: You can download at https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/tools/tv-extension/archive just selecting TV extension 3.1.2 and your Operating System

Answer (score 0):

I usually have a fresh install of SDK when doing an update.

I had some issues with the latest studio and 2018 TV. Make sure you install the Samsung Extension Manager under Extra in Package Manager.

Make sure you are using Samsung Certificate when prompted, it will ask you to login with Samsung ID and generate a cert. Make sure your device is already with Device Manager. It will pre-populate DUID for the device-profile.

In the past you had to 'allow to install application' on you device in device manager, you may/may not have to do that on 2018s.

I can be done. I hope these tips help.

Answer (score 0):

For a fix to my problem, make sure your computer and tv device are connected through a public internet network. My situation is my laptop and tv are connected through a proxy.

For complete steps, please check here: [Installing App to Samsung Tizen TV with Partner Level Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52984854/installing-app-to-samsung-tizen-tv-with-partner-level-certificate/63374661)